# .net conditional compilation according to referrer assembly

Tags: silverlight, compilation, conditional-statements, portable-class-library

I have a WCF service interface in a portable class library referenced by both silverlight and service implementer. It is like this:

```
#if SILVERLIGHT
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginTest(AsyncCallback cb, object state);
    void EndTest(IAsyncResult ar);
}
#else
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Test();
}
#endif
```

now I referenced it from SL and got a compilation error which shows that the contract is sync version and not supported by SL. I think the reason is that there is no SILVERLIGHT defined in the portable library. But I don't want to define one because it is referenced by another non-silverlight libraries. Is there any way to let compiler automatic select right version to compile according to the category of the referrer project without modifying the portable library?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You would need to have two separate assemblies with the different APIs.

You might be able to keep a single portable library if you just use an async method returning Task instead of the Begin/End pattern.  You can get async support on Silverlight with the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) package, but I'm not sure if you can use that for WCF on Silverlight or not.

Comment: When I use channel model to access WCF service in SL, async contract is an available option. I am not sure if there are another better choices. Facing the coming deadline I have no time to explore other probabilities. I have resolved the problem using namespace. I have appended two new sub-namespace SL and WCF. In silverlight I refer to async contracts in namespace SL and in other situation to sync version in namespace WCF. I am sure what you have said is the trend and I am about to explore it carefully after this project. Thanks, Daniel.